# Slideshow by changing background-image CSS attribute using JQuery in Drupal 7

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, drupal

I want to create a slideshow by targeting the background-image attribute of a div element and changing it using Jquery. I got the following code from some website but couldn't manage to make it work.

```
var images=new Array('/ccl/sites/default/files/Speed_Queen_Equipped.jpg','/ccl/sites/default/files/Speed_Queen_Equipped2.jpg','/ccl/sites/default/files/Speed_Queen_Equipped3.jpg');
var nextimage=0;
doSlideshow();

function doSlideshow(){
    if(nextimage>=images.length){nextimage=0;}
    $('#homeBanner')
        .css('background-image','url("'+images[nextimage++]+'")')
        .fadeIn(500,function(){
            setTimeout(doSlideshow,1000);
        });
}
```

I have placed the code for my banner in the page.tpl.php page of my drupal project:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div id="homeBanner" class="row">
        <div class="container">
            <div id="homeBannerText">
                <h1>Consulting Cleaning Laundry</h1>
                <p>Le spécialiste des solutions propreté au Maghreb et en Afrique.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's the relevant CSS by which the background-image attribute is applied:

```
#homeBanner{background-image: url(/ccl/sites/default/files/Speed_Queen_Equipped.jpg); height:600px}
#homeBannerText{ padding-top:230px; color:white; font-size: 200%;}
#homeBannerText>h1{ font-size: 70px;}
```

I did include the reference to my script at the bottom of my html.tpl.php page and checked that it is indeed showing on my HTML with developers tools:

```
<script src="sites/all/themes/bootsfire/js/main.js"></script>
```

Nothing is happening though, what am I doing wrong ? How can I change my code to get the behavior I expect ?

Comment: Would you be open to a pure CSS solution for this, using animations?

Comment: Yes, I would, what do you propose ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can actually be achieved purely with CSS by using animations, with no need for any JavaScript.

Here's a quick example I threw together for you. I was a bit pressed for time so it's a little rough around the edges but it should, at least, point you in the right direction. I also, unfortunately, didn't have time to write up a full explanation but, if anything needs to be clarified, please let me know.

- [More information on animation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation)
- [Browser support for animation](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation)

```css
body{margin:0;}
div{
    -webkit-animation:bg linear 20s infinite;
    animation:bg linear 20s infinite;
    background:url(http://lorempixel.com/1920/480/sports) center center no-repeat;
    background-size:contain;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0 0 25%;
    max-width:1920px;
}
@-webkit-keyframes bg{
    5%{
        background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/1920/480/sports);
    }
    20%,30%{
        background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/1920/480/city);
    }
    45%,55%{
        background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/1920/480/nightlife);
    }
    70%,80%{
        background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/1920/480/technics);
    }
    95%{
        background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/1920/480/business);
    }
}
@keyframes bg{
    5%{
        background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/1920/480/sports);
    }
    20%,30%{
        background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/1920/480/city);
    }
    45%,55%{
        background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/1920/480/nightlife);
    }
    70%,80%{
        background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/1920/480/technics);
    }
    95%{
        background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/1920/480/business);
    }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: I adapted your code to make it work for me on my website. However, I'm still a bit annoyed because I can't get it to fit on the right side of the window: http://snag.gy/BJxEH.jpg like it used to when I only had a bakcground-image and no slideshow : http://snag.gy/tmOLc.jpg.

Comment: Got a Fiddle to share to illustrate that problem? If it's not related to the actual slideshow itself (i.e., transitioning the bg image), you may be better served posting it as a new question.

Comment: I haven't got a fiddle but I edited my answer to show the screenshots.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific as to what the problem is between those 2 screenshots? Looking at them, all I can see is a size difference between the images. If that's the issue then try adjusting the `background-size` property or removing it altogether.

Comment: I managed to get around the issue, it was actually a width:100% property that messed up my slideshow somehow. Anyway, thanks for all your help.

Comment: You're welcome, glad you got it working :) And thanks for the rep.